# Empty string consideration for substring and permutation

Tags: java

I'd like to know how to make a decision about the following ?

#### A. Is empty string considered a substring of:

1. Another empty string
2. A non-empty string

#### B. Is empty string considered a permutation of:

1. Another empty string

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can test the first two yourself with [`contains`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#contains%28java.lang.CharSequence%29):

```
/* 1 */ System.out.println("".contains(""));
/* 2 */ System.out.println("abc".contains(""));
```

```
true
true
```

As for your last question, it seems analogous to asking *how many permutations of the empty set are there?*, and the answer to that is `0! = 1` - i.e. yes, the empty set is a permutation of itself, therefore the empty string can be considered a permutation of itself, in the mathematical sense.

Answer (score 1):

1. Yes.
2. Yes.

I do not know what implementation of permutation you have in mind, but in general, yes, based on the fact that empty is a subset of empty, you should expect that an empty string is a valid permutation of another empty string.

```
String foo = "hello!";
String bar = "world";
String baz = "";
String qux = "wor";
String ipsem = "";

System.out.println(foo.contains(bar));               //false
System.out.println(foo.contains(baz));               //true
System.out.println(baz.contains(foo));               //false
System.out.println(bar.contains(qux));               //true
System.out.println(baz.contains(ipsem));             //true
```

Answer (score 1):

Write some *real* tests with Junit!

Also be careful with [interned Strings](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#intern%28%29), the last test `isNotConsideredIdenticalVariable` needs a trick to stop compiler optimization (namely automatic interning).

```
import org.junit.Assert;
import org.junit.Test;


public class EmptyStringTest {

    @Test
    public void isConsideredSubstringOfEmpty() throws Exception
    {
        Assert.assertTrue("".contains(""));
    }


    @Test
    public void isConsideredSubstringOfNonEmpty() throws Exception
    {
        Assert.assertTrue("NOT EMPTY".contains(""));
    }


    @Test
    public void isConsideredEqual() throws Exception
    {
        Assert.assertEquals("", "");
    }


    @Test
    public void isConsideredIdenticalLiteral() throws Exception
    {
        Assert.assertTrue("" == "");
    }


    @Test
    public void isNotConsideredIdenticalVariable() throws Exception
    {
        String firstInstance = "a".replaceAll("a", "");
        String differentInstance = "";
        Assert.assertFalse(differentInstance == firstInstance);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you are asking this with the tag "java", I assume that you are referring to the `String` type.

A Java empty `String` *can* be considered as a substring of another empty or non-empty String ... in the sense it can be generate using `String.substring()`.  (Not all empty String instances can be produced that way, but if you are comparing Strings using `equals`, that is not relevant ...)

The Java `String` API doesn't define a `permute` operation.  This means we cannot say how it behaves.  The second part of the Question is unanswerable.

---

If you are talking about some other model of what a string is, then the answer depends *entirely* on the model.

If you are (in effect) for on advice on how to model strings ... then I don't think your Question is answerable.  Again, the Answers would depend on how you have defined the *rest* of your string model.

But if you wanted my advice, then you need to consider how you are going to *use* the string model.  Is it useful for the set of substrings of a string to include the original string?  Is it useful for the set of permutations of a string to include the original string?  What are the logical consequences ...

Finally, [this Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String_%28computer_science%29#Formal_theory) includes a "formal theory" of strings.  To my non-mathematician's eye, it looks good, but the page doesn't cite any references that appear to relate to the formal theory section.